# How can i get dropdown on hover and how to apply redirecting link to the sub dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html

I created the dynamic dropdown list by dependency.i.e populating a dropdown by selecting the list of the other dropdown. below is the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
        {
            document.getElementById("subcategory").length = 0;
            switch (listindex)
            {
                case "Php" :
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select framework","");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("Cakephp","Cakephp");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Wordpress","Wordpress");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Codeigniter","Codeigniter");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("Joomla","Joomla");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Magento","Magento");
                    break;


                case "Javascript" :
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select framework","");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("D-Jango","D-Jango");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("Angular","Angular");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("Prototype","Prototype");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[4]=new Option("jQuery","jQuery");
                    document.getElementById("subcategory").options[5]=new Option("Backbone","Backbone");
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
   </script>
</head>
<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
<body>
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Please specify language:
        <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="">Select Language</option>
            <option value="Php">Php</option>
            <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Please select framework:
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            document.write('<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory"><option value="">Please select framework</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
                <option value="">Please select framework</option>
            </select>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now i want to get the dropdowns to be on hover instead of onclick. and want to apply redirecting links to the sub dropdown options.
Kindly help me how can i do this. thank you

Comment: Any body please help me on this

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. Do you want both the dropdowns to be triggered on hover of them?

Comment: @KamalaHB, yes both the dropdowns and redirecting links to the second dropdown

Comment: Instead of making select work with hover, use a custom dropdown.

Comment: @abhikr7, custom dropdown in the sense??

Comment: Anybody, please help me on this